# Aggregate array of subdocuments into single document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My document looks like the following (ignore timepoints for this question):

```
{
    "_id": "xyz-800",
    "site": "xyz",
    "user": 800,
    "timepoints": [
        {"timepoint": 0, "a": 1500, "b": 700},
        {"timepoint": 2, "a": 1000, "b": 200},
        {"timepoint": 4, "a": 3500, "b": 1500}
    ],
    "groupings": [
        {"type": "MNO", "group": "<10%", "raw": "1"},
        {"type": "IJK", "group": "Moderate", "raw": "23"}
    ]
}
```

Can I flatten (maybe not the right term) so the `groupings` are in a single document. I would like the result to look like:

```
{
    "id": "xyz-800", 
    "site": "xyz", 
    "user": 800, 
    "mnoGroup": "<10%", 
    "mnoRaw": "1", 
    "ijkGroup": "Moderate", 
    "ijkRaw": "23"
}
```

In reality I would like the `mnoGroup` and `mnoRaw` attributes to be created no matter if the attribute `groupings.type = "MNO"` exists or not.  Same with the `ijk` attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ***[$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/)*** to read the groupings array by index in the first project stage and ***[$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/)*** to project optional values in the final project stage. Litte verbose, but'll see what I can do.

```
db.groupmore.aggregate({
    "$project": {
        _id: 1,
        site: 1,
        user: 1,
        mnoGroup: {
            $arrayElemAt: ["$groupings", 0]
        },
        ijkGroup: {
            $arrayElemAt: ["$groupings", -1]
        }
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        _id: 1,
        site: 1,
        user: 1,
        mnoGroup: {
            $ifNull: ["$mnoGroup.group", "Unspecified"]
        },
        mnoRaw: {
            $ifNull: ["$mnoGroup.raw", "Unspecified"]
        },
        ijkGroup: {
            $ifNull: ["$ijkGroup.group", "Unspecified"]
        },
        ijkRaw: {
            $ifNull: ["$ijkGroup.raw", "Unspecified"]
        }
    }
})
```

Sample Output

```
{ "_id" : "xyz-800", "site" : "xyz", "user" : 800, "mnoGroup" : "<10%", "mnoRaw" : "1", "ijkGroup" : "Moderate", "ijkRaw" : "23" }
{ "_id" : "ert-600", "site" : "ert", "user" : 8600, "mnoGroup" : "Unspecified", "mnoRaw" : "Unspecified", "ijkGroup" : "Unspecified", "ijkRaw" : "Unspecified" }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I added a filter and took the first element so we weren't hardcoding.  `mnoGroup: {$arrayElemAt: [{$filter: { input: "$cohorts", as: "cohort", cond: {$eq: ["$$cohort.cohortType", "MNO"]}}}, 0]},`

Comment: yeah I thought about that last night only to forget this morning. Sorry about that.

Comment: No worries.  You pointed me in the right direction then I got to exercise my brain.  I think I just graduated 3rd grade in MongoDB.  Onto new adventures.